# Is there any way to capture desktop screen shot using flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I want to capture whole screen in my flex application. I googled a lot but found ways only to capture air window screen and I want to capture user's whole screen. I got a way using "NitroScreenCap" but I'm not understanding how can I implement this in my application. Could anyone please suggest me some working solution of this?

Comment: Are you talking about a web application running in a browser? Then the answer is: you can't. Otherwise please add more information about your environment.

Comment: I'm creating a window application using flex and adobe air. And I want to capture desktop screen from this window application within some time interval.

Comment: I think you have to use a [native extension for AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/index.html) - that's what NitroScreenCap does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageSnapshot.captureImage() to capture your flex application screen, try this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        layout="vertical"
        verticalAlign="middle"
        backgroundColor="white">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.IUIComponent;
            import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;

            private function takeSnapshot(source:IBitmapDrawable):void {
                var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(source);
                var imageByteArray:ByteArray = imageSnap.data as ByteArray;
                swfLoader.load(imageByteArray);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Array id="arr">
        <mx:Object col1="Row 1, Col 1" col2="Row 1, Col 2" />
        <mx:Object col1="Row 2, Col 1" col2="Row 2, Col 2" />
        <mx:Object col1="Row 3, Col 1" col2="Row 3, Col 2" />
        <mx:Object col1="Row 4, Col 1" col2="Row 4, Col 2" />
        <mx:Object col1="Row 5, Col 1" col2="Row 5, Col 2" />
        <mx:Object col1="Row 6, Col 1" col2="Row 6, Col 2" />
    </mx:Array>

    <mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
        <mx:Button label="Take snapshot of DataGrid"
                click="takeSnapshot(dataGrid);" />
    </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{arr}" />

        <mx:SWFLoader id="swfLoader">
            <mx:filters>
                <mx:DropShadowFilter />
            </mx:filters>
        </mx:SWFLoader>
    </mx:HBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this code piece is only to capture flex screen and I want to capture user's whole screen using flex.

Answer (score -2):

To capture DisplayObject in my Flex applications, I use the class [PNGEnc](http://labs.insideflex.com/flextraining/ImageToPDF/srcview/source/info/flexination/actionscripts/PNGEnc.as.html).

Here is a code example of his use :

```
var c2 : DisplayObject = c.getChildAt(0) as DisplayObject;  

var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(c2.width,c2.height);
bd.draw(c2);                                    // Graph copy
var screen:ByteArray = PNGEnc.encode(bd);       // PNG format conversion
```

Next, I send my ByteArray to save it on a server in Java but I think you can also use

> new FileReference().save(screen)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need to capture user's whole screen as print screen key works. Hoping for a positive response.